# How to convert csv column from 12 hour AM PM to 24 hour time?

Tags: csv

I have a 1900 line csv list from an export that looks like this:

```
date,time,ampm
01/01/2024,3:43:19,pm
01/01/2024,3:43:19,am
```

I'm trying to loop an if statement that basically says:

```
if [[ third csv entry  = pm ]]; then
    second csv entry numbers between , and : += 12
    print modified line
else
    print original line
fi
```

resulting in

```
date,time,ampm
01/01/2024,15:43:19,pm
01/01/2024,3:43:19,am
```

This looks like a nightmare in bash but it's what I know how to use the most effectively. I don't know python enough to be able to work through it. I'm open to other suggestions as well.

Comment: Split the line on the comma, then split the time on the colons and increment the hour for PM settings. There are several ways to split a string in bash. In your case, I would use the regex matching built into bash. Have a look at the bash _man-page_ and search for the string `=~` (which is the regex matching operator). Alternatively, use `awk` instead of bash.

Comment: Your formula isn't correct since you need to *subtract* 12 for 12:xx:xx AM

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it with GNU sed, using the `e` flag to the substitution command, which executes the pattern space as a shell command.

```bash
sed '2,$ {
    y/,/ /
    s|.*|date -d "&" +%m/%d/%Y,%T,%P|e
}' infile
```

`2,$` is there to leave the header line alone.

`y/,/ /` replaces all commas with blanks.

The substitution command reformats the line as a `date` command that looks like

```bash
date -d "01/01/2024 15:43:19 pm" +%m/%d/%Y,%T,%P
```

where the `-d` argument is now in a format that `date` understands, and the `+...` part formats the output to look like the desired output.

Result:

```
$ sed '2,${y/,/ /;s|.*|date -d "&" +%m/%d/%Y,%T,%P|e}' infile
date,time,ampm
01/01/2024,15:43:19,pm
01/01/2024,03:43:19,am
```

Answer (score 1):

With perl

```bash
perl -MTime::Piece -F, -lape '
    next if $. == 1;
    $t = Time::Piece->strptime($_, "%d/%m/%Y,%I:%M:%S,%p");
    $F[1] = $t->strftime("%-H:%M:%S");
    $_ = join ",", @F;
' file.csv
```

```
date,time,ampm
01/01/2024,15:43:19,pm
01/01/2024,3:43:19,am
```

This avoids having to call out to `date` for every line.

The Time::Piece datetime parser is finicky: the input string must exactly match the expected format, which is why I have to add the leading zero.

---

With bash, I'd write:

```bash
{
    IFS= read -r header
    echo "$header"
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        date -d "${line//,/ }" '+%D,%-H:%M:%S,%P'
    done
} < file.csv
```

Comment: The `01/01/1234` date format is ambiguous (is it day/month or month/day?). I'd strongly recommend `%Y-%m-%d`

Comment: `%D` is "same as `%m/%d/%y`, i.e., two-digit years instead of four.

Answer (score 1):

Adding some samples to cover `12:xx:xx am/pm`:

```
date,time,ampm
01/01/2024,3:43:19,pm
01/01/2024,3:43:19,am
01/01/2024,12:43:19,pm
01/01/2024,12:43:19,am
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }                                    # split 2nd field on ":" character; place subfields into array a[]
NR>1  { split($2,a,":")                                 # split 2nd field on ":" character; place subfields into array a[]
        offset = 0
        if ($3 == "pm" && a[1] != 12) offset =  12
        if ($3 == "am" && a[1] == 12) offset = -12

        $2 = a[1] + offset ":" a[2] ":" a[3]            # rebuild 2nd field
      }
1                                                       # print current line
' dt.csv
```

This generates:

```
date,time,ampm
01/01/2024,15:43:19,pm
01/01/2024,3:43:19,am
01/01/2024,12:43:19,pm
01/01/2024,0:43:19,am
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's a way to do that reading line by line using loop in bash

```
#!/bin/bash
input_file="input.csv"
output_file="output.csv"
    
while IFS=',' read -r date time ampm;do
        if [[ "${ampm,,}"=="pm" ]]; then
                convTime=$(date -d "$date $time" +"%H:%M:%S")
                echo "$date,$convTime,$ampm" >> "$output_file"
        else
                echo "$date,$time,$ampm" >> "$output_file"
        fi
     done < "$input_file"
```

Results in the below output

```
01/01/2024,15:43:19,pm 
01/01/2024,03:43:19,am
```

Comment: `"${ampm,,}" == "pm"`

Comment: Also, you need to pass the ampm value to date, otherwise how will it know that hour 3 means 15?

Comment: Your solution does not handle 12:xx:xx AM correctly.